# chartjs-plugin-zoom: separate x- and y-axis zoom when mouse above axis

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

With `chartjs-plugin-zoom`-plugin for ChartJS I am trying to separate x- and y-axis zoom when the user scrolls above an axis. I can not get this working and I am now wondering if this might not be possible. I expected this to be possible through the `overScaleMode`-argument, like displayed in the below configuration. This did not make the appropriate changes.

```
plugins: {
    zoom: {
        pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'xy',
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'xy',
            overScaleMode: 'xy',
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement this zoom behaviour?

As an alternative I am thinking about adding buttons besides the graph to turn the one the zoom-directions on or off. Or are these type of buttons already implemented into the software (or through another plugin)?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I faced the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: No. I implemented the buttons mentioned in the question.

Comment: What version of chart.js are you using? It should be supported in v3.x and above (and latest chartjs-plugin-zoom)

Comment: It works for chart.js v3.0.0 and above

Comment: I am using 2.8. Maybe I'll give 3.0+ a change, however, the work around is fine for now as well (buttons).